# Write function type on multiple lines in Idris

Tags: idris

How do I split a type declaration into multiple lines in Idris? Types should drive development. So they may become quite long and not fit on screen. Like this one:

```
addMatrices : (augent : Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> (addend: Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)
```

Comment: I don't know Idris, but you can probably make a new type (or an alias, if idris allows it) like `Matrix Nat Nat Set`, which will reduce your declaration by some amount.

Comment: Al.G. Thank you for proposing your solutuion. I'll try to find out more about aliases in Idris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with formatting only, you can do it as you've done,

```
addMatrices : (augent : Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
              (addend: Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
              Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)
```

The [docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html) say

> New declarations must begin at the same level of indentation as the preceding declaration.

Similarly, the [book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) only says, in Section 2.4.1 *Whitespace significance: the layout rule*,

> ... in any list of definitions and declarations, all must begin in precisely the same column.

Since the new line isn't a new declaration, I take this to mean the new line can start at any level of indentation, so

```
addMatrices : (augent : Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
       (addend: Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
          Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)
```

and other variants would also be valid.

Alternatively, following on from Al.G.'s comment, you can use a type alias, but if `rowCount` and `columnCount` aren't in scope, which I'm guessing they aren't for you, you'll need a type-level function, which is a generalisation of a type alias. It's a function that returns a type.

```
Matrix : Nat -> Nat -> Type -> Type
Matrix rows cols elem = Vect rows (Vect cols elem)
```

Then you'll have

```
addMatrices : (augent : Matrix rowCount columnCount element) -> 
              (addend: Matrix rowCount columnCount element) -> 
              Matrix rowCount columnCount element
```

which isn't much shorter.

To be honest, I'd look at using shorter names and take advantage of any obvious context

```
addMatrices : (augent : Vect r (Vect c elem)) -> (addend: Vect r (Vect c elem)) -> Vect r (Vect c elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out when inspecting types in Atom:

```
addMatrices : (augent : Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
              (addend: Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)) -> 
              Vect rowCount (Vect columnCount element)
```